# ZF redirector. Why redirect page doesn't get HTTP_REFERER?

Tags: zend-framework, redirect, controller, http-referer

I have two actions in controller:

```
function indexAction()
{
    $this->_redirect('/index/welcome/');
}

function welcomeAction()
{
    echo isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
```

After redirect it returns always null. How to fix it?

Comment: I think you will need to manually setup a session variable to store the referrer's url.

Comment: Actually I did it. Thinking this is one way to solve it for now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect (301,303) works on the HTTP level and not the HTML level, i.e. a browser is not aware of the redirect with the exception of the information to update the URL.

Answer (score 0):

This may be:
function welcomeAction()
    {
    echo isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';
    }

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it's specified that a client must send the `Referer`, so it's very likely that your browser simply doesn't send the `Referer` with the redirected request. You can check that using FireBug or some other tool that allows you to inspect the request headers. The `Referer` header is described in [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.36).

Comment: Take a look at the headers that are sent from the server to the client and vice versa.